# Laravel view, layout and variables transfer

Tags: php, view, laravel, laravel-blade

my laravel view structure is like this:

```
 /views/layouts/default.blade.php
```

containing

```
<html>
@yield('header')
<body>
    @yield('navigation')
    @yield('content')
    @yield('footer')
</body>
```

following by

```
/views/partials/footer.blade.php
/views/partials/header.blade.php
/views/partials/navigation.blade.php
```

In my header view i have a var $title
I'm trying to set it dynamically trought the controller on the home page.

so in my view located in /pages/index.blade.php
I got this

```
@layout('layouts.default')
@section('header')
  @render('partials.header')
@endsection

@section('navigation')
  @render('partials.menu')
@endsection

@section('footer')
  footer
@endsection

@section('content')
@endsection
```

I read somewhere that the title var should be passed throught the controller but i can't do it :(

i tried this without any success.$title is undefined in header partials views..

```
class Home_Controller extends Base_Controller {
    public $layout = 'layouts.default';
    public function action_index()
    {
        $this->layout->nest('header', 'home.index')->with('title', 'James');
        $posts = Post::with('author')->all();
        return View::make('home.index');

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel's Blade templating engine you can use either `@render` or `@include` to render views.

However, if you use `@render`, the rendered view won't inherit data from the current view. So, if you need variables etc. to be inherited, you need to use `@include`. See the [docs on templating](http://three.laravel.com/docs/views/templating) for more information.